Problem converting date in character format to date format
My data:
dput(head(days_of_N$Begin_N)) 

c("1989-02-20", "1989-02-22", "1989-02-25", "1989-03-08", "1989-03-11", "1989-03-21"

I used the following code to convert date, which is in character format, to date format:
days_of_N$Begin_N <- as.Date(days_of_N$Begin_N, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

Initially this is how date looked, but after using above code, the date values turned to NA.

We can't help you without a sample of your data, so please run dput(head(days_of_N$Begin_N)) and copy the result into a codeblock in your question.

dput(head(days_of_N$Begin_N))
c("1989-02-20", "1989-02-22", "1989-02-25", "1989-03-08", "1989-03-11",
"1989-03-21")

Two things: 1) the dmy separators are "-" in your data, but you are using "/" in as.Date(), 2) the order of your character strings is ymd. Try this: days_of_N$Begin_N <- as.Date(days_of_N$Begin_N, format = "%Y-%m-%d").

Also, I have added your example data to your question so you can see how to do it for any future questions that you may have. Happy coding!

Since your character class date strings are already in the form "%Y-%m-%d" as.Date can cast them to class Date per default
dates <- as.Date(c("1989-02-20", "1989-02-22", "1989-02-25", "1989-03-08", 
  "1989-03-11", "1989-03-21"))

class(dates)
[1] "Date"

This is the universal way a Date class (ISO 8601) is stored in R, and this cannot be (easily) modified (nor should one want to do it).
What's often wanted is to change the character representation of this class, e.g. with format.Date
format.Date(dates, format="%d/%m/%Y")
[1] "20/02/1989" "22/02/1989" "25/02/1989" "08/03/1989" "11/03/1989"
[6] "21/03/1989"

which prints class character.
